# Spacy (phrase) matching multiple attributes

Tags: spacy

I wish to match the phrase "Education program" but with any word in between. So suppose I have the following text:

```
text = "Education is a way to program life. This sentence has nothing to do with education"
```

And I set the pattern to be:

```py
pattern = [{'LOWER': {'LEMMA': 'education'}}, {'IS_SENT_START': False, 'OP': '*'},{'LOWER': {'LEMMA': 'program'}}]
```

However, when I do the following I get an insane amount of matches for the above:

```py
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add('edu', None, pattern)
doc = nlp(text)
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # Get string representation
    span = doc[start:end]  # The matched span
    print("Match ID: {}\nString ID: {}\nStart: {}\nEnd: {}\nText: {}\nSentence: {}".format(
      match_id, string_id, start, end, span.text, span.sent))
```

Just wondering what I'm doing wrong here? I tried switching LOWER and LEMMA as well, without any luck.

### Edit1:

The given solution works but not for the following text:
`text = 'This account was created by a prior staff member for our county Tobacco Education Program.'`. I have spacy version `2.2.4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may define the `pattern` as

```
pattern = [{'TEXT': {'REGEX': '(?i)^education\w*$'}}, {'IS_SENT_START': False, 'OP': '*'}, {'TEXT': {'REGEX': '(?i)^program\w*$'}}]
```

Then, the result will be

```
Match ID: 2541531027590536373
String ID: edu
Start: 0
End: 6
Text: Education is a way to program
Sentence: Education is a way to program life.
```

The `(?i)^education\w*$` regex matches a string that starts with `education` (`^education`) and then has any 0 or more word chars (letters, digits or underscores, see `\w*`) till the end of string (here, end of token, see `$`) in a case insensitive way (`(?i)`). The `(?i)^program\w*$` pattern is analogous.

Comment: Any chance you can take a look at the second text example I've provided. It doesn't work in that instance. Could it be a bug?

Comment: @sachinruk Code freezes when I try to find a match in `Education Program`, but does not when I use `Education program`, so there is a bug I believe. `pattern = [{'LOWER':{'LEMMA': 'education'}}, {'IS_SENT_START': False, 'OP': '*'}, {'LOWER': {'LEMMA': 'program'}}]` works for `Education Program`, but not for longer phrases. I think there is some bug with how `LEMMA` token is handled in the pattern. For now, I'd suggest to fall back to regex, `pattern = [{'TEXT': {'REGEX': '(?i)^education\w*$'}}, {'IS_SENT_START': False, 'OP': '*'}, {'TEXT': {'REGEX': '(?i)^program\w*$'}}]`

Answer (score 1):

`{'LOWER': {'LEMMA': 'education'}}` isn't a valid pattern, and unless you turn on validation (see below), the `Matcher` silently discards ill-formed attributes, so in effect this pattern is treated like `{}`, which matches any token, which is why you get so many results.

You can use either

```
{'LOWER': 'education'}
{'LEMMA': 'education'}
```

but they can't be nested.

Use `Matcher(nlp.vocab, validate=True)` for more thorough validation when writing patterns. (It's off by default because it makes adding patterns a lot slower.)